# Anybody Else Seen http://ask.recipelabs.com/

Tags: discussion

I know that [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) has a list of copy-cat sites and legitimate SE 1.0 sites, but I searched over there for [http://ask.recipelabs.com](http://ask.recipelabs.com/) and didn't see anything.  It certainly looks like an SE site, although I see no mention of Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow except in the source (meta tags)

```
    <meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

Looks like we are way more popular, they only have a handful of active users.

Is there anything worth doing with it?  Alert the admin that there's a similar SE 2 site?  Leave it?

EDIT: Found it on meta.SE in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-1-0-sites/5#5).

Answer (score 4):

As you've noted, it's a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.

Sometimes we try to migrate content from SE 1.0 sites, but in this case I would leave it alone.  First of all, it's very late in the game to be considering that, but even more importantly, the vast majority of their questions don't meet our most basic standards.

Half of what I see on the front page is recipe requests.  Then there's health questions, meta questions, localized questions, general polls, etc.  Assuming they even *wanted* to migrate their content, which is by no means certain, it would take us forever to sort through all of the noise just to get a few good questions, several of which might be duplicates anyway.

I suppose it wouldn't hurt to contact one of their admins and ask if they'd be interested in linking here, since their own Q&A site doesn't get used heavily.  My suspicion, though, is that either they wouldn't be interested or we'd end up having to deal with all the merging baggage.

If it were a high-traffic site then I might be singing a different tune, but as it is, I'd rather just ignore it.

Comment: I guess we can funnel all the folks who through a fit saying we are too strict over there... ;)